# DataGridview not updating to DB

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using winforms application with a datagridview. 
Problem :Trying to save the edited data in the database
Code:

```
     private void FillData(string selectCommand)
        {
            SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connString);
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            string selectCommand = "select * from Table1";
            da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(selectCommand, connString);
            conn.Open();
            ds = new DataSet();
            SQLiteCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(da);
            da.Fill(ds,"Design1");
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0] ;
            dataGridView1.DataMember = "Design1";
      }
 private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connString);
            try
            {

                dataGridView1.EndEdit();

                for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].AcceptChanges();
                }

                da.Update(ds.Tables[0]);


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }

        }
```

Not sure if this is an issue with Sqlite.
There are no errors, except it does not update in the DB. Once I stop the application and reload it, edits are saved in DB.

Thank you
Sun

Comment: you mean that you dont see the changes is the winform? But they are are saved/updated in the DB?

Comment: @feco: I dont see the changes in the DB. Once I restart the application the form loads with the initial values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should reverse the order of AcceptChanges and Update lines

```
            dataGridView1.EndEdit(); 
            da.Update(ds.Tables[0]); 
            // Just accept on the table, no need to do row by row
            ds.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
```

[See the Remarks here for a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges.aspx)

Let me say also, keeping all that vars around is not a good practice.
They could introduce side effects and bugs difficult to track.
In special mode, the connection should be disposed as fast as possible, encapsulanting in a `using` statement. (Provided that you explicity request the connection  pooling feature -> `"Pooling=True;Max Pool Size=100;"`)

For example:

```
     private void SaveData(DataGridView dgv, string selectCommand)  
     {  
        using(SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open(); 
            SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(selectCommand, connString); 
            SQLiteCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(da); 
            DataTable dt = dgv.DataSource as DataTable;
            da.Update(dt);
            dt.AcceptChanges();
        }
     }
```

Comment: I reversed the order to the above suggested. But a DBConcurrencyException is raise. Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records.

Comment: In the FillData I don't see the connection closing. In your click event you open another connection but use the SqLiteDataAdapter created in the click event. As I have said, don't keep the connection opened.